# Find all entries on a list within Kibana via Elasticserach Query DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

Could you please help me on this? My Kibana Database within "Discover" contains a list of trades. I know want to find all trades within this DB that have been done in specific instruments (ISIN-Number). When I add a filter manually and switch to Elasticserach Query DSL, I find the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "obdetails.isin": "CH0253592783"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "obdetails.isin": "CH0315622966"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "obdetails.isin": "CH0357659488"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Since I want to check the DB for more than 200 ISINS, this seems to be inefficient. Is there a way, in which I could just say "show me the trade if it contains one of the following 200 ISINs?".

I already googled and tried this, which did not work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "obdetails.isin": [ "CH0357659488", "CH0315622966"],
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

The query works, but does not show any results.

Comment: You might need to share your index to help clarify the issue. But I'm guessing your `obdetails.isin` is an analyzed field which may not work with terms as intended. Adding a field of type `keyword` should help.

Comment: You are a genius. Issue solved. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To conclude. A field of type `text` is analyzed which basically converts the given data to a list of terms using given analyzers etc. rather than it being a single term.
Given behavior causes the terms query to not match these values.

Rather than changing the type of the field one may add an additional field of type `keyword`. That way a terms queries can be performed whilst still having the ability to match on the field.

```
{
  "isin": {
    "type" "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above example will add an extra field called `obdetails.isin.keyword` which can be used for terms. While still being able to use match queries on `obdetails.isin`